# No module named blog

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbie in django.Now I'm following a book named *Python Web Development with Django* and creating a light blog.With the app ***blog*** and sqlite3 chosen for testing, an error came up when running ./manage.py syncdb.

The error is that

```
Error: No module named blog
```

This is part of my `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite.blog',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',

)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/var/db/django.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Here is all of the **model.py** in blog app:

```
from django.db import models

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DataTimeField()
```

I've searched through the similar questions in stackoverflow, but those resolutions doesn't work for me.

Comment: I hope your code indentation is ok, cause here it looks like its not

Comment: @Kapo I just pasted it from my script.It's sure to be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try blog only:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    .......
    'blog',
    ......
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.But how do you know that removing the 'mysite.' helps?

Comment: it will depends on the path of your settings