# ImportError: No module named chosen

Tags: python, django

I recently have downloaded a django project off of github (it is confidential so I cannot share the code). And I am writing a script that should be processing some of the models. I changed the correct information in the settings and have created my basic script for testing that looks like the this:

```
from appname.models import *
print "hello world"
```

When I try `python manage.py shell < script.py` I get `ImportError: No module named chosen`. Why is this and what can I do to get my script to run?

here is the full traceback:

`Setting Django settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named chosen`

Comment: make sure that the app you downloaded from github has all of its dependencies also installed on your pc. -

Comment: If it's a half-decent project, it has a `setup.py` from which you can tell what its dependencies are. Look at the `install_requires` argument to the `setup()` call. Then you need to make sure these dependencies are also installed for your script.

Comment: what is the contents of `script.py`?

Comment: It is looking for a 'chosen' module. Maybe your INSTALLED_APPS settings? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321385/no-module-named-blog

Comment: Wow, I read that as No module name chosen meaning that I had not chosen a module name, not that there was a module named chosen I did not have. Thank you, this was rather idiotic of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the ["chosen" django plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-chosen/0.1) needs to be installed.